# Copying database works on emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This works on the emulator but not on my phone. At least it seems so because it does not find the table when I query it on the phone.

This my class that inherits from SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String DB_NAME = "klb_db.sqlite";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;

private String dbPath;
private Context context;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    this.context = context;
    dbPath = "/" + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}

public void initializeDatabase() {
    try {
        File file = new File(dbPath + DB_NAME);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(
                    "klb_db.sqlite");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In dbadapter, open method:

```
    public DBAdapter open() {
    dbHelper.initializeDatabase();
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

In activity that uses it:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    QuizDAO quizDAO = new QuizDAO(this);
    quizDAO.open();
    Cursor cursor = quizDAO.getQuestion(10);
    Toast.makeText(this, cursor.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to increase you bytes

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

to

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
```

**EDITED**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    QuizDAO quizDAO = new QuizDAO(this);
    quizDAO.open();
    Cursor cursor = quizDAO.getQuestion(10);
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    Toast.makeText(this, cursor.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: first delete the previous file, or first uninstall the app then try

Comment: I uninstalled the app first yes, then tried again. I can't delete the file since /data directory is not accessible when debugging on the HTC Desire non-rooted.

Comment: listen, do onething, first check the size of klb_db.sqlite(original) and then check the size klb_db.sqlite(copied) on device

Comment: you can temporary switch the output folder like dbPath = "/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/dbname"

Comment: Okey, done that and it is the same size in the asset folder as it is in the SD card so the writing seems alright.

Comment: Do I need any permissions to write to the /data directory on my phone?

Comment: Updated question. Thats all I have.

Comment: try with my edited code, move cursor to first position then run